# HTML PAYPAL FORM

Tags: html, paypal

I wrote a code. I need to add the Paypal button when you press "Submit" and when you pay for consultation then I got email with question. Any help ?
I never use PayPal.

```
<h3>Prescription</h3>

<div class="container">
  <form action="action_page.php">

    <label for="consultation">consultation</label>
    <input type="text" id="consult"

    
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" style="height:200px"></textarea>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    
    </form>
  
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Check the paypal documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide and make 2 routes (url paths) on your server:

- one for 'Create Order'
- one for 'Capture Order' that takes an `id` to capture as input

You can use the Checkout-PHP-SDK for the routes' API calls to PayPal, or your own HTTPS implementation of first getting an access token and then doing the call. Both of these routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should verify the amount was correct and store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending this email you want, or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller. In the event of an error forward the JSON details of it as well, since the frontend must handle such cases.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .